# How to watch for changes to files in a folder using npm?

Tags: npm, next.js, watch

I'm trying to set up some form of auto-deployment using the npm package watch. Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 60000",
    "watch:start": "watch \"npm run start\" ./build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
      ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "watch": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

The app runs fine and it watches the correct folder, but when it detects a change, I get an infinite loop of EADDIRINUSE errors, because it is simply trying to re-run the app, not restart it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: make a task that will restart tour server, maybe usage of pm2

Comment: Gave that a go already. I end up with a process online and running, but with 0 uptime and continuously restarting. Trying to debug that